# jQuery not found: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, django, static

I receive the error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined".

Below is the component/templates/component/update.html template which is defined as:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %} 

{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'component/js/component.js' %}"></script>

<h2>Create new component</h2>

{% include 'snippets/form-snippet.html' with form=form %}

{% endblock %}
```

I have the script saved at component/static/component/js/component.js. The file is found since in the console.log i can read: "GIVE ME SOME LOG". However I receive the error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". Apperently jQuery is not found but how to fix this? The component.js file is defined as follows:

```
console.log("GIVE ME SOME LOG")

$(document).ready(function(){
    hideShow()
})

$('#id_component_type').click(function(){
    hideShow()
});

function hideShow(){
  if(document.getElementById('id_component_type').options[document.getElementById('id_component_type').selectedIndex].value == "k_v")
    {
        $('#id_length').parents('p:first').hide();
        $('#id_k_v').parents('p:first').show();
    }else
    {
        $('#id_length').parents('p:first').show();
        $('#id_k_v').parents('p:first').hide();
    }
}
```

The base.html file is defined as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>{% block head_title %}Solarus Calculation Tool{% endblock head_title %}</title>
        {% include 'snippets/css.html' %}
    </head>

    <body>
        {% include 'snippets/nav.html' %}

        <div class='container'>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content %}
        </div>

        {% include 'base/js.html' %}

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          {% block jquery %}{% endblock %}
        })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The js.html is defined as:

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: I'm gonna ask the obvious. Is jQuery included in the project?. For example like so:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525994/how-to-use-jquery-with-django

Comment: How is your base.html? let us see the structure of your js calls

Comment: I added base.html and js.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should consider adding this script `<script src="{% static 'component/js/component.js' %}"></script>` inside the `{% block jquery %}{% endblock jquery %}`

That way, Django will load it after the `jQuery` file

Instead of this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      {% block jquery %}{% endblock %}
    })
</script>
```

Create the block that way to avoid double `script` tags

```
<script> --> remove this script
    $(document).ready(function(){
    })l;
</script>
{% block jquery %}{% endblock %}
```

so when you call that block, you can open the `script` tag

```
{% block jquery %}<script>< /script> {% endblock %}
```

or even call something from other websites

```
{% block jquery %}
    <script src="https://cdn.something.com"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'component/js/component.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I cannot add the <script src="{% static 'component/js/component.js' %}"></script> inside the {% block jquery %}{% endblock jquery %} I get more errors

Comment: updated my answer, your structure was not good enough. try to adapt the structure of my answer, feel free to let me know if you get stuck

Comment: Yes that worked, thanks for the tip. 

However for now I simply have the script directly in my component create.html and update.html templates. This is not according to DRY principle but it's a lot simpler.

Comment: Thanks this worked. But why didn't hardcoding like `/static/path_to_js.js` didn't work?